# clmm does not compute random effect

Tags: r, statistics, mixed-models

for my research participants (n=N) ranked 4 pictures, producing 4*N cases.
Now I want to control for the participants and pictures. I included the participantID (here=PerNO) and pictureID, but it only works for PicID. What i do wrong?

Many thanks for any idea.

Here the output with participantID, after that you'll find the working output with PictureID

````
> summary(var.with.random)
Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation

formula: Int ~ PicSex + Posture + (1 | PerNO)
data:    x

link  threshold nobs logLik  AIC     niter    max.grad cond.H
logit flexible  668  -917.62 1847.24 423(331) 3.80e-06 NaN   

Random effects:
Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev. 
PerNO  (Intercept) 5.38e-07 0.0007335
Number of groups:  PerNO 167 

Coefficients:
     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
PicSex1   0.4107         NA      NA       NA
Posture  -0.4035         NA      NA       NA

Threshold coefficients:

 Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2 -1.12189         NA      NA
2|3 -0.01118         NA      NA
3|4  1.11189         NA      NA 
```

**Output with PictureID:**
```
> var.with.random <- clmm(Int~PicSex + Posture +(1|PicID), data = x)
> summary(var.with.random)
Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation

formula: Int ~ PicSex + Posture + (1 | PicID)
data:    x

link  threshold nobs logLik  AIC     niter    max.grad cond.H 
logit flexible  668  -896.18 1804.35 317(954) 7.20e-04 1.2e+02

Random effects:
Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
PicID  (Intercept) 0.3262   0.5711  
Number of groups:  PicID 16 

Coefficients:
     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
PicSex1   0.4428     0.3195   1.386    0.166
Posture  -0.4528     0.3198  -1.416    0.157

Threshold coefficients:
 Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2 -1.21490    0.28418  -4.275
2|3 -0.01622    0.27953  -0.058
3|4  1.18597    0.28276   4.194
````

Comment: Seems the estimated variance between PerNo is numerically 0. I'm guessing that the answers are very similar between individuals but vary somewhat between pictures.

Comment: @Oliver Ok, but if the variance is low, there should be no problem to compute the coefficients, they would be (close to)  the same as the computation without the  random effect. Why does it say NA?

Comment: I haven't checked the source code for the implemented algorithm. My best bet is they use some standardized measure for the variance matrix (such as `solve(t(X)%*%V%*%X)` for [beta](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2290687?seq=1), and similar for the random effects). This inversion depends on the estimate of the variance parameters, and would likely fail for very small variance estimates.